# PHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' - associative array

Tags: php, parse-error

I wrote a code that worked perfectly fine, but then I reinstalled my operating system, and now  when I try to run this, I keep getting this error. I am using IIS 8.0, WebMatrix, and PHP 5.3.

This is the piece of code in question:

```
<?php 
     if (!$me->get_details()['quote']) : //<--error is here
?>
     <p class="quote">Write some motivational quote.</p>
<?php
     else :
?>
     <p class="quote"><?= $me->get_details()['quote']?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Function get_details() returns an associative array with data from the database.

What could possibly go wrong here?

Comment: Check your PHP version and check array dereferencing in the manual

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dereference in PHP 5.3 this way.

You need to do:

```
$result = $me->get_details();

if (!$result['quote']) :
```